# Javascript - Timezoneoffset and LocaleString are different

Tags: javascript, date

I've seen lots of problems with timezone in javascript but I didn't find one specific as below.

When I use new Date() in JS, I get a different timezone from LocaleString.
I've tested this in some browsers with colleagues and in some the behavior are ok.

E.g., on my browser I get:

```
new Date()
-> Mon Oct 05 2015 20:49:14 GMT-0200 (E. South America Daylight Time)

new Date().toLocaleString()
-> "10/5/2015, 7:50:11 PM"
```

The correct time is 7:50 PM. Why are their behavior different? And mostly important, how could I create new Date() but showing as 19:50 GMT-0300?
I don't want to set the timezone manually as we have daylight saving time, and in that period I would have to change the code.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: It's not daylight time here (Brazil, Sao Paulo) yet as the browser says when creating through new Date()

Comment: In my case new Date() changes when i turn off and on option in windows "Adjust for daylight saving time automaticly". So basicly what new Date() returns depens on your system settings.

Comment: Can you tell us which browser and OS you are using?

Comment: the format show from the raw date in the console is the UTC flavor, but it's the exact came time as dates which happen to be formatted locally.  you can adjust the offselt of the actual date so that it LOOKS correct in your locale, using the offset: `new Date(new Date() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000) )` where you can sub the first inner "new Date" for an existing date. also, `new Date(new Date() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000) ).toISOString().split(/\D+/)` gives you local date parts to self-format if needed.

Comment: Here it's a Windows 7, and I'm getting the same behavior in IE and Chrome, so it indeed appears to be dependent on system settings. The thing is I won't be able to change the settings as policies in my company :(

I think adjusting the offset won't work as when it indeed changes to daylight saving time, I would have to multiply by 20000 instead of 30000 (in my country).

There is probably something in the configuration I didn't see yet, as for some colleagues with same browser and OS, they get a different result..

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.toLocaleString()` method result is dependent on your OS locale, langiage and timezone settings. For example your script may fail in my browser if I have different datetime format set. I would suggest to use a library like [Moment.Js](http://momentjs.com/) which provides better timezone handling and date formatter features compared to native functionality provided bt JS.

In my Chrome browser I'm getting following result. We switched to DST 2 days ago:

[image]

Comment: Woa! It must be something in the config of my browser. I used moment.js + moment-timezone (which is a really nice JS lib.. thanks for pointing that out), and I get the same wierd behavior.. `var a = moment("2015-10-06T14:00:00Z")` then `a.tz('America/Sao_Paulo').format('ha z')` returns me 11AM when it's 10AM. Interestingly enough, if I use New York as the timezone, it also shows one hour ahead. Any ideas on what I could check ? (:

Answer (score 0):

Posting here just in case someone comes up with the same issue.. 
What seems to be my problem was that my `TZ` variable in Windows was set `EST5EDT`. That was probably causing the issue. When I set it to `BST3` which is my timezone, both `new Date()` and `.toLocaleTimeString` returns the same time, (and the correct time) even with the "`Automatically adjust timezone settings`".

Now I just need to confirm if when I enter daylight time it will work too.